# how to fix it ? cloud foundury on node server with nfs image upload problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud, cloud-foundry, multer

First, I'm sorry about my English ability.

It is bound to the node server nfs service in the cloud foundry
There is no problem reading and writing text in the nfs service
So it does not seem to be a question of access 
but image upload is problem.
I tracked the problem.
Refer to the busboy module in the Multer module
In the BusBoy module, call Multipart.prototype.write
There is a problem here.
this is sourse code

```
Multipart.prototype.write = function(chunk, cb) {
        logger.debug('Multipart.prototype.write');
//  logger.debug('Multipart.prototype.write chunk : '+chunk);
    logger.debug('Multipart.prototype.write cb : '+cb);
  var r;
    logger.debug('Multipart.prototype.write r : '+r);
  if ((r = this.parser.write(chunk)) && !this._pause){
      logger.debug('Multipart.prototype.write failure r undefined');
       cb();
  }else {
      logger.debug('Multipart.prototype.write success');
    this._needDrain = !r;
    this._cb = cb;
  }
};
```

It is a locally successful log
[image]

This is the log that failed in the cloud.
[image]

Multipart.prototype.write Keeps calling in the cloud
Do you know where to call it?
How to solve it?

Comment: Since NFS is involved, it is my first suspicion. Try to mount the NFS volume (or any NFS volume) locally and see if the app still works locally.

Comment: I'm a junior developer, so I do not see how to proceed
Do you have any samples related to it?    However, the nfs service and bindings are done in the cloud and there is no problem reading and writing the txt file  
I do not know why I should test it again locally